# Ad Studio Audience Size Minumim?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ad-studio

We are wanting to serve truly 1 to 1 social and search ads. I wasn't sure if it would be possible to do that via Ad Studio or Journey Builder. Are there minimum audience size requirements to load serve an ad via SFMC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are different minimum Advertising Audience sizes for all networks.

According to the [**documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000318352&type=1) the numbers are:

- **Facebook**: minimum 20 (recommended 100)
- **Google AdWords**: minimum 1000
- **LinkedIn**: minimum 300
- **Twitter**: minimum 500
- **Snapchat**: minimum 1000
- **Pinterest**: minimum [**100 matches**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313954&type=1) (special case)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If that's all for now, you can mark it as the accepted answer and this will close the question.